# How can I call a defined function in python?

Tags: python

> Although I have visited multiple websites, I cannot find the exact example that I have used in this code here. From def msg(room): until the game over image is where I have defined the function. At the very bottom is where I call all the functions, but I am unsure on how I can call this specific one.

```
def msg(room):
    if room['msg']== '': #There is no custom message
        return "You have entered the " + room['name']+'.'
    else:
        return room ['msg']

def getChoice(room,dir):
    if dir == 'N':
        choice = 0
    elif dir =='E':
        choice = 1
    elif dir=='S':
        choice =2
    elif dir == 'W':
        choice = 3
    else:
        return -1

    if room['directions'][choice] == 0:
        return 4
    else:
        return choice

if pointsUser == "1":
    print ("You encounter a sunken home, and your metal detector tells you there is something inside.")
    print ("You have found phosphorus, but now you must collect other elements.")
    print ("You must use your keys to navigate around the rooms to find the elements hidden insdie.")
    dirs = (0,0,0,0) #default NESW

    entrance = {'name':'Entrance Way','directions':dirs,'msg':''} #dictionary is a collection of names and properties, keys and values. Each dictionay here has 3 properties. 
    livingroom = {'name':'Living room','directions':dirs,'msg':''}
    thethehallway = {'name':'Hallway','directions':dirs,'msg':''}
    kitchen = {'name':'kitchen','directions':dirs,'msg':''}
    diningroom = {'name':'Dining room','directions':dirs,'msg':''}
    familyroom = {'name':'Family room','directions':dirs,'msg':''}
      #directions are tuples: Rooms to the (N, E, S, W)
    entrance['directions'] = (kitchen,livingroom,0,0)
    livingroom['directions'] = (diningroom,0,0,entrance,)
    hallway ['directions']=(0,kitchen,familyroom)
    kitchen ['directions'] = (0,diningroom,entrance,hallway)
    diningroom ['directions'] = (0,0,livingroom,kitchen)
    familyroom['directions']=(0,hallway,0,0)

    #rooms where the elements may be
    rooms = (livingroom,hallway,kitchen,diningroom,familyroom)
    rooms_with_eggs= random.choice(rooms)
    elemDelivered = False
    room = entrance
    print ("Welcome, Adventurer! Can you find the precious elements?")

    while True: #nested while loop 
        if elemDelivered and room['name'] == 'Entrance Way':
            print ("You've picked up the elements and returned")
            print ("To the entrance of the sunken home. You can now swin away,")
            print("congratulations!")
            break;
        elif not elemDelivered and room['name'] == room_with_elem['name']:
               elemDelivered = True
               print (msg(room) + "There are the elements with dark figure")
               print("in the corner... You have found your elements, now swim away quickly!")
        else:
               print (msg(room))
               room ['msg'] = "You are back in the" + room['name']

               stuck =  True
               while stuck:
                   dir = input("Which direction do you want to  go: N,E,S or W?")
                   choice = get_choice(room,dir)
                   if choice == -1:
                       print ("Please enter N, E, S, or W?")
                   elif choice == 4:
                       print("You cannot go in that direction.")
                   else:
                       room = room ['directions'][choice]
                       stuck = False

else:
    print("Game over")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple example,
First define a function like this,

```
def showMsg(myMsg):
    print(myMsg)
```

Now, call the above defined function like this,

```
showMsg('My Message!')
```

Output: `My Message!`

In your code, you can call your `msg` function like this,

```
room = {msg: 'my msg', name: 'xyz'}
msg(room)    # make a dictionary of name room = {} and pass to this function
```

room is just a dummy to show an example.

Comment: Hello Abdur, thank you for your reply. I now understand how to define simpler functions, but with such extensive code like the one I have inputted, how can the same basic principles of calling functions be applied?

Comment: I have updated my reply and given an example (first function of your code) as well.

Comment: @user10849974 let me know if still there is any confusion? Please accept this answer.

Comment: Hi Abdur, sorry for the late reply. I am just having a bit of trouble applying what you have explained despite it being very clear. How would I program it so that the entire defined function runs as soon as the condition in the if statement has been met? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user10849974 sorry for being late. Just do this, `if (condition) { func_name()}`. Replace `func_name` with name of your function, it will execute as your `if`statement will met the condition.

Comment: @user10849974 let me know if you have any other queries. Please `accept` this answer.

Comment: Hello Abdur, I have solved the issue in my program another way but this is also very informative.

Comment: Sounds good. Still, if you have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To create a function that could be defined and then called, you must create a main  function called main(). Then, call this function after the if statement like so:

if ....: #This is where the condition you need to be met should be 
main() # You do this to call the function and begin your code

There were other errors with indentation and NameErrors that were fixed before the code could run, but what I said previously was the solution.